# Is it possible to make the last p within a specific div class have specific css?

Tags: html, css

To get the last `p` to have no margin, you could do `last-of-type`, however this doesn't work once you start having `p` nested within other `divs`.

Is it possible to have specific css for the last `p` within a specified class?

For example:

```
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="banner-message1">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-message2">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

To specifically make it so that the `<p>2</p>` has certain styling, but not the `<p>1</p>`

The css of `div.my-container p:last-of-type` would seemingly apply to both `<p>1</p>` and `<p>2</p>` since they are the last `p` within the parent `div` (in this instance `banner-message1` and `banner-message2`)

https://jsfiddle.net/hygzq3ab/

Here's a jsfiddle, which has both a margin-bottom on the last `p` tag and then also padding of the container, so that the last `p` element looks essentially like it has a double bottom margin. `last-of-type` does not seem to work since it is contained within other div classes.

Example code for that would be `div.my-container p:last-of-type { margin-bottom:0; }`

Comment: The answer of Fabrizio Calderan is correct, you can read also here some specification about [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `<p>` is always contained in a `<div>` then you could target that paragraph with

```
.my-container > div:last-of-type p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

You need to target the paragraph inside the last div (also `:last-child` instead of `:last-of-type` would work as well in this specific example).

---

But if your last `<p>` is not always contained in a `<div>` then you could target it with

```
.my-container > div:last-child p,
.my-container > p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Here you *must* use `:last-child` instead of `:last-of-type` or — in case the last `<p>` is not wrapped in its own `<div>` — you will also target the paragraph contained in the last `<div>`

Comment: This is very good but there is also the possibility that there is a p tag at the end without being inside a div. It would still be the "last p tag" within div.my-container. See https://jsfiddle.net/rw864cav/

Comment: There is actually a situation where this code doesn't work, where you put a div with many p's inside of it. Seems to be fixed by adding :last-child to the p. https://jsfiddle.net/oah7xbqL/

Comment: In this case you need to specify last-child also on p if you have multiple siblings paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you asking for?

**html (your fiddle does have alot same ids of same element)**

```
<div class="my-container">
<div class="banner-message">
  <p>
  1
  </p>
</div>
<div class="banner-message">
  <p>
  2a
  </p><p>
  2b
  </p>
</div>
<div class="banner-message">
<p>
aaa
</p>
</p>
  <p>
  3
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

**and css:**

```
.banner-message:last-child p:last-child {
  color: red
}
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You also should use that: `last:child`

```
 .my-container > div:last-child p {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```